# Can a SQL INSERT fail without raising an exception in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Are there any cases where an `INSERT` in SQL (specifically Oracle-PL/SQL) can fail without an exception being thrown?  I'm seeing checks in code after `INSERT` where it verifies that `SQL%ROWCOUNT = 1 ELSE` it raises its own user-defined exception.  I don't see how that can ever happen.

Comment: What if the insert is from a query and more than one row is inserted?

Comment: What if your disk on the database server is full?? Don't laugh - this happens in production systems at times.....

Comment: exception when others then null ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can't **fail** without an exception, no.  Probably the developer who wrote the code didn't know that.

An after statement trigger could conceivably delete the row just inserted.  And of course an INSERT...SELECT might find no rows to insert, and so would result in SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the trigger-based issue @mcabral mentioned, you could have an insert that is successful but inserts other than 1 row.  For example, the `insert into blah(col1) select col2 from foo` style of insert.

Answer (score 2):

As @TonyAndrews and @GinoA mentioned, there are several ways an `INSERT` could return something other than exactly one row (triggers, `INSERT INTO tablename SELECT...` syntax).

But the bigger issue is that you're in PL/SQL. As such, the `SQL%ROWCOUNT` value can be used as a condition to determine the program execution flow including issuing `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` statements.

Even with just raising a user-defined exception, the calling PL/SQL block can handle the exception itself.

EDIT: Someone should modify the question title to indicate PL/SQL (as indicated in the question itself), since that's not the same thing as SQL scope the title suggests.

Comment: I've adjusted the title to mention exceptions and PL/SQL